# AuthorizeNet - How to make a payment on Test Mode

Tags: authorize.net

I am unable to do payment on test mode, I get this error message "The payment gateway account is in Test Mode. The request cannot be processed."

Is there a way to do it in Test Mode?

Comment: If you have test mode set at the gateway or in your request, the gateway will only validate the API Login and Transaction key and return success/fail for that only, it will not attempt a transaction.

Comment: can you describe more on how actually are you trying to make the payment,  which language SDK are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Test Mode on Authorize.Net really only provides basic connectivity testing and works only with one-time transactions. For testing anything more complex (such as tokenization or recurring billing), it's best to use [a sandbox account](http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox/) in live mode.